# I have a board and list model with the correct relationships, how do i correctly build a form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple Board and List Model. A board can have many lists and a list can have many boards.

I have a board created and i am trying to create a list on that board.

So i navigate to the board i created. In the url it is www.example.com/board/1 and i click a link to create a list. It then needs to get the board_id from the url and record it in my Board_List Models foreign key field when i create a list. My Board_List join model contains the 2 foreign key fields called board_id and list_id.

Can someone explain how i would setup my controller and my form to get this to work correctly?

**Board Model**

```
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :boards

has_many :board_lists
accepts_nested_attributes_for :board_lists, :allow_destroy => true
has_many :lists, through: :board_lists
```

**List Model**

```
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :lists

has_many :board_lists
accepts_nested_attributes_for :board_lists, :allow_destroy => true
has_many :boards, through: :board_lists
```

**Board_List Model**

```
belongs_to :board
belongs_to :list
```

**List Controller**

```
def new
  @list = List.new
end

def create
  @list = current_user.lists.build(list_params)
  @list.save
end

Private
  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit( :title)
   end
```

**List Form**

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>   

  <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'noEnterSubmit' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>    

<% end %>
```

**Edit**

Here below is how i can link a list to a board in the console and this works but i am not sure how to do it with a form. I have it so the user creates a board first and submits the form. Then the user is taken to the board (www.example.com/board/1).

I want it so the user clicks a link to create a list and that renders a form for them to create a list that is tied to the board they were currently on. I am not sure how to get that board_id that was in the url tied to the list they create.

Console

```
user = User.first
board1 = user.boards.create
list1 = user.lists.create
BoardList.create(board: board1, list: list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First build some boards in your controller.

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  def new
    @list = List.new
    # Seed the list with boards
    3.times { @list.boards.build }
  end

  def create
    @list = current_user.lists.build(list_params)
    @list.save
  end

  # Ruby keywords should always be lowercase!
  private
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:title, boards_attributes: [:name])
     end
end
```

And then in your form you use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) to generate fields for the nested boards.

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>   

  <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'noEnterSubmit' %>

  <%= f.fields_for :boards do |bf| %>
    <%= bf.hidden_field :id %>
    <%= bf.label :name, "Name" %>
    <%= bf.text_field :name %>
  <%- end -%>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried this but in my BoardList Model it didn't record the foreign key fields so they are not linked together. Also i don't want any fields for the board. I already have a board created i just want the list i create to be tied to that board. I edited my question explaining it a little better and how i am able to do it in the console but i don't know how to do it in the with a form.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). You can have your `lists` routes nested under `boards` routes:

in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :boards do
  resources :lists
end
```

And now to create a new list the path should be `/boards/1/lists/new`.

In your `lists_controller.rb`:

```
def new
  @board = Board.find(params[:board_id]) #params[:board_id] automatically set from the nested route
  @list = List.new
end
```

Finally your form:

```
<%= form_for([@board, @list]) do |f| %>   

  <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'noEnterSubmit' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>    

<% end %>
```